# Mypy specifying Literal Output

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

My function returns a tuple of two values, one of which is string with one of two possible values, say "a" or "b". This string is retrieved from the URL and indeed in theory can be something else - in which case I raise a Valuerror. However, it seems that mypy does not see my error, and still upset with string to Literal conversion.  What is the proper way to solve that?

```py
def _get_listing_info(txt: str) -> Tuple[int, Literal["a", "b"]]:
    
    findInfo = re.search(r"ios-app://\d+/item/(\w+)/(\d+)", txt)
    if findInfo is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Failed to establish listing type from `{txt}`")

    
    tp, listting_id = findInfo.group(1), int(findInfo.group(2))
    if tp not in {"a", "b"}:
        raise ValueError(tp, url)

    return listting_id, tp
```

Mypy raises an issue with:

> Expression of type "tuple[int, str]" cannot be assigned to return type "Tuple[int, > Literal['a', 'b']]"
> Tuple entry 2 is incorrect type
> Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['a', 'b']"
> "str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['a']"
> "str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['b']"

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because x is a `Literal["a", "b"]` only if `x` is equal to `"a"` or `"b"` **and no other string** ([see `Literal` semantics here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#core-semantics)).

I could subclass `str` like this:

```
class CustomStr(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

which is equal to everything, including `"a"`. To verify this:

```
>>> "a" == CustomStr()
True

>>> CustomStr() == "a"
True

>>> "b" == CustomStr()
True

>>> CustomStr() == "b"
True
```

(so this `str` ends up being equal to both `"a"` and `"b"`, regardless of whether `CustomStr()`'s `__eq__` or the literal string's `__eq__` gets called)

Checking whether this custom string equals `"a"` would not be enough to make it `Literal["a"]` because it is also equal to every other string, which violates `Literal` semantics.

In general, being able to subclass types and override their methods (which is completely type safe in mypy) makes any sort of narrowing based on their methods very hard to do. This applies to the `__contains__` / `in` method of your example's `{"a", "b"}` set, and also the `__eq__` / `==` of `findInfo`.

Hypothetically, your example could type check, if:

1. `re.search` somehow indicated to `mypy` it returns an object whose type is exactly `str`, and not potentially a subclass
2. because of your use of a `set` **literal**, `mypy` inferred that `__contains__` returning `True` means that the argument to `__contains__` is `==` with one of the elements in that `set` (which also assumes `__hash__` is implemented correctly, again something that `mypy` cannot guarantee for an arbitrary subclass of `str` that `re.search` is type hinted to return).

However, mypy doesn't take advantage of either of these facts in your example.

To make your example actually type-check, you could change it to this:

```
def _get_listing_info(txt: str) -> Tuple[int, Literal["a", "b"]]:
    findInfo = re.search(r"ios-app://\d+/item/(\w+)/(\d+)", txt)
    if findInfo is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Failed to establish listing type from `{txt}`")

    tp, listting_id = findInfo.group(1), int(findInfo.group(2))

    if tp == "a":
        return listting_id, "a"

    if tp == "b":
        return listting_id, "b"

    raise ValueError(tp, "abc")
```

And it is 100% safe because we know that `re.search` cannot return a `CustomStr` that satisfies those `==`s but ends up not being an `"a"`.